# Adding menus to C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

Yes I am having issues, I spent a good 30 minutes on attempting to figure this out. (Not including the time I spent searching for an answer via the internet.) For the people who have a hard time understanding what I mean...

[image]

**Using Microsoft Visual C#**

Comment: What kind of application is it? WPF? WinForms? Web?

Comment: And what is the question? You need such menu where?

Comment: I'm editing form1.cs - A Windows Form Application. I need such menu on the top left of my application. As shown in the image.

Comment: drag and drop from toolbox, and you are done

Comment: @LarsTech: +1 from me...lol....internet was PETERNET and browser was WIREFOX....

Answer (score 11):

In Winforms its called a "MenuStrip"

[MSDN: MenuStrip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx)

[Tutorial: Visual Studio Windows Application MenuStrip Driven Applications](http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~thicks/Tutorials/Visual-Studio-Windows-App-Form-MenuStrip-Apps/Visual-Studio-Windows-App-Form-MenuStrip-Apps.html)